# Cannot connect from one container to another

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have running 3 docker containers. app, mongodb and elasticsearch.

when I connect to mongodb from app it looks like this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<name_of_the_container>/<database_name>');
```

when I try to connect from app to elasticsearch it doesn't work:

```
const esOptions = {
    log: 'error'
};
esOptions.host = '3dominatores:9200';
const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client(esOptions);
```

it doesn't yeld any error when it's connecting but it does shout loud when I try to access elasticsearch: `Error: No Living connections`.

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  3dominator:
    build: .
    image: 3dominator:0.1
    container_name: 3dominator
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      DB_ENV: container
        ports:
          - "3004:3004"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    links:
      - 3dominatordb
      - 3dominatores
  3dominatordb:
    image: mongo:3.4.1
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongodb/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    container_name: 3dominatordb
 3dominatores:
    image: elasticsearch:latest
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    container_name: 3dominatores
    links:
      - 3dominatordb
networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

PS: I am new to `docker` and `elasticsearch`

**EDIT**

I found this error up above:

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2017-03-23T15:45:04Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST http://3dominatores:9200/projects/project/58d3ed8059ff2d001e5ae4a2 => socket hang up
  at Log.error (/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:225:56)
  at checkRespForFailure (/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:240:18)
  at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:162:7)
  at ClientRequest.wrapper (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:19)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:345:9)
  at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)


/app/src/models/ProjectModel.js:56
            if (err) throw err;
                     ^
```

Comment: BTW elasticsearch is up and running, I can curl it...

Comment: I can even do `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/projects/project/58d3ed8059ff2d001e5ae4a2' -d "{\"field\": \"value\"}"` and it returns success